# Speed up scipy.stats.hypergeom calculations

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm currently calculating the hypergeometric survival function (1-cdf) for a large number of comparisons (~900M). As it stands, the `scipy` implementation is relatively slow (at least compared to the R version, which is ~100x faster):

```
    
    def calculate_hypergeometric_overlap_nums(object_ontology_count, overlaps):
        '''
        Calculate hypergeometric 1-cdf 
        '''
        fftot = 40071
        ffb = 375
        

        if overlaps <= 0: return [1.0]
        overlaps_adj = overlaps - 1

        val = stats.hypergeom.sf(overlaps_adj, fftot, object_ontology_count, ffb)
    
        return [val]
       


results = list(tqdm(map(self.calculate_hypergeometric_overlap_nums, object_ontology_counts, oe_overlaps)))

 > 1394400it [02:32, 9156.94it/s]
```

The above is the timing for ~1.4M comparisons. I see the following SO post that discusses modifying some underlying C libraries:

[How to efficiently vectorise hypergeomentric CDF calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831438/how-to-efficiently-vectorise-hypergeomentric-cdf-calculation)

Which seem to speed up the process by ~100x, but this process is a bit over my head. Are there other ways of quickly calculating `scipy.stats.hypergeom.sf` ?

Comment: Why are you using `map`? SciPy's implementation is vectorized so you can pass the arrays directly. If you don't want to compute for special cases like `overlaps <= 0`, you can use masks `overlaps_adj = overlaps[overlaps>0] - 1`.

Comment: I see what you mean but do not have any suggestions unless it is faster to cache results and look them up so the actual CDF is calculated only for unique argument combinations.  Alternatively if you could settle for approximate results maybe it would be good enough to make an interpolation matrix once and then interpolate to estimate the CDFs for your actual data?